# How can I make .htaccess files in a subfolder not execute?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloud

I am creating a cloud storage project, and I want users to be able to upload any file. In particular, I want people to be able to upload `.htaccess` files, but I don't want Apache using these files as this is a security concern. How can I prevent Apache from using the user uploaded file, while still using my own .htaccess file in a parent folder?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/9513/34011) is helpful reading. Directives near the www-root are applied first, subfolders are used later and may overwrite previous settings.

There are some things you can do:

- Don't use .htaccess files at all, not even in other directories. If you have a dedicated server, you can edit the server config file, which is much more efficient. It will allow you to set `AllowOverride None`, which will prevent Apache from using .htaccess files at all. Instead, you can accomplish the same by putting your rules in the server config file. You'll need to restart Apache every time you make a change, and making an error in the server config file will prevent Apache from starting until it is fixed.
- Store your files as random characters without an extension, make it impossible to access any files directly, and instead rely on a database to map a filename to a file. This allows you to store files securely, while not dumping everything in your database.

You cannot put anything in your .htaccess file that would prevent .htaccess files in subdirectories to be ignored, because [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) only works in directory context, not in .htaccess context.